# Можно в приложении создавать динамичски layout ?

Tags: android

имею

```
view =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
```

можно вместо R.layout.item загрузить  layout из строки String, которую считаю с сайта или добавлять динамически нельзя ?

Comment: я хотел сохранить на сервере loyout и по мере необходимости менять его на сервере, а в приложении загружать из сети. так возможно ?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что верно понял ваш вопрос, но попробую:

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("item", "layout", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

А затем полученный `id` используйте как обычно.

Comment: если я правильно понял, это считывания из файлов ресурса,
а мне надо создавать его из данныйх, полученных из сети через http:// запрос при каждом выводе данных. я хотел сохранить на сервере loyout и по мере необходимости менять его на сервере, а не в  приложении. так возможно ?

Comment: Нет, так не удастся. Можете попробовать на клиенте разобрать получаемый файл лэйаута, построив дерево его элементов, а затем создавать нужные view, добавляя их в нужные контейнеры.

Comment: а можно во время выполнения менять свойства  loyout , например изменить размер шрифта ? или мне придется использовать несколько loyout с разным размером шрифта?

Comment: Да, можно — `textView.setTextSize()`.